# How to join two different line specifically in text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so i'm doing a text file question and 90 percent of the work is done. Although i'm printing two names at end of my code (both on different line) , i'm trying figure out how to print them on same line specifically like this :("Best students: " name + " " + name) (could have more than 2 names depending on the text in the text file). I have tried using end= " " to put them on same line and it had space in between them which worked fine.Until I had to put in specific text before it e.g print("Best Students :",name,end=" ") but that gave the following output :

Best Students : Michael Murphy Best Students : John Kelly

Expected output : Best Students : Michael Murphy, John Kelly
Best mark: 89

Any tips or ideas that could help me out would be massively appreciated.

Thank you

```
file = "students.txt"
with open(file,"r") as f:
q = []
for i in f:
  i = i.split()
  number = i[0]
  q += (number,)
highest = max(q)


with open(file,"r") as f:
for i in f:
   i = i.split()
   number = i[0]
   if highest == number:
     name = " ".join(i[1:])
     print("Best Students :",name,end=" ")
# print("Best Mark:",highest)
# Best Students : Michael Murphy, John Kelly
# Best mark: 89

Stduents.txt
64 Mary Ryan
89 Michael Murphy
22 Pepe
78 Jenny Smith
57 Patrick James McMahon
89 John Kelly
22 Pepe
74 John C. Reilly
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: sorry code is posted now

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file,"r") as f:
    names = ""
    for i in f:
       i = i.split()
       number = i[0]
       if highest == number:
         if names != "": names += ", "
         names += " ".join(i[1:])

print("Best Students :",names)
```

Modify the second part like this. I got this output

```
Best Students : Michael Murphy, John Kelly
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like a flag, that we would only print the "Best student" in the first iteration.

```
file = "students.txt"
with open(file,"r") as f:
    q = []

    for i in f:
      i = i.split()
      number = i[0]
      q += (number,)
    highest = max(q)

studentFound = False
with open(file,"r") as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.split()
        number = i[0]
        if highest == number:
            name = " ".join(i[1:])
            if(not studentFound):
                print("Best Students :",name,end=" ")
                studentFound = True
            else:
               print(",",name, end=" ")

    print("\nBest Mark:", highest)
```

Result

```
Best Students : Michael Murphy , John Kelly 
Best Mark: 89
```